# Get-AzureWebsite cmdlet returns no instances, but my site is live. How can I query and update it?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I'm having trouble updating an Azure-hosted web application via Visual Studio Team Services. While trying to diagnose the problem, I seem to have run into some more fundamental problems with querying my Azure websites that I'm unable to work around.

- I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio Team Services and Azure hosting 
  to build and deploy a web application project. I've installed Azure
  Powershell for management.
- I've created a Web App project using ASP.NET MVC and checked it in to
  my .git repository on VS Online.
- Using the VS Team Services tools, I've created a build definition that
  includes a deployment step to my Azure host. This build runs
  automatically upon check-in and worked fine the first few times it ran -
  the site deployed and was immediately available at
  [mywebapp].azurewebsites.net.

Starting yesterday, the deployment step has failed at the following lines:

```
Get-AzureWebSite -Name [mywebapp] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-AzureWebSite -Name [mywebapp] -Location North Europe
##[error]Conflict: Website with given name [mywebapp] already exists.
```

I ran Azure Powershell to see if I could get some more information, but I can't even seem to query the existing site (according to my Azure management portal the site is still running, and it responds when I navigate to its URL). Running the command:

```
(Get-AzureWebsite -Name [mywebapp]).Instances.Count
```

returns zero instances, *despite the fact that the site is running*.

Can anyone recommend a way to get more verbose information about my Azure sites, or suggest a way to force the deployment step to overwrite the existing site? This is for development purposes, so I have no need to preserve anything from the existing deployment.

Comment: Can you make sure you are using the correct/right subscription?

Comment: And if you are you should then raise a support call with Microsoft on the Azure portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell is behaving as if you're in the wrong subscription...  What goes Get-AzureWebSite (no params) return - is you're site in the list?  Can also try:

```
(Get-AzureWebSite [mywebapp]).Enabled
```

I don't think .Instances.Count is always populated (it's not on my sites).

Comment: Thanks! Simple errors are often the easiest to overlook - switching to the correct subscription fixed my issue. Sorry for the very late acknowledgement.